# Zebra printer printing out of sequence

Tags: node.js, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I am sending prints to zebra printer from Node.js server. I am sending bulk prints 4-6 pages in a for loop.
But I am getting the sequence of prints out of sequence.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: How are you sending the bulk prints?  As individual files, in one file, or using the ^PQ command?  Are you sending directly over an IP network, or to thin clients?  It would help also if you included a sample of your ZPL.